# Como usar quebra de linha no C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho uma etiqueta e nessa etiqueta tenho um campo que é muito grande.

Preciso quebrar a linha, para ir para linha debaixo quando chegar a um determinado número de caracteres.

```
etqfracpic1.Add("Cas: " + reader[10].ToString()); 
// como estou passando o comando
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Me desculpe segue o código completo.

```
List<string> etqfracpic = new List<string>();
    List<string> etqfracpic1 = new List<string>();

    public frmEtqFracPic(string guiapic)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txt_guia.Text = guiapic;
    }
    private void etqfrac()
    {
        conex.Open();
        SqlCommand comando;

        StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder();
        Query.Append("   SELECT                                                                                     ");
        Query.Append("   CAST(0 AS bit) AS SELECIONAR                                                               ");
        Query.Append("   ,SC.C2_NUM                                                                                  ");
        Query.Append("   ,SB.B1_DESC                                                                                ");
        Query.Append("   ,SC.C2_XNOMFA                                                                              ");
        Query.Append("   ,SC.C2_XNPAIS                                                                              ");
        Query.Append("   ,SC.C2_XLOTEF                                                                              ");
        Query.Append("   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SB.B1_PESO AS NUMERIC(15, 3))) + ' ' + SB.B1_XSEGUM AS PESO      ");
        Query.Append("   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(SB.B1_PESBRU AS NUMERIC(15, 3))) + ' ' + SB.B1_XSEGUM AS PESBRU  ");
        Query.Append("   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST( SC.C2_XDTFAB AS DATE),103) AS DATAF                            ");
        Query.Append("   ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST( SC.C2_XDTVALI AS DATE),103) AS DATAV                           ");
        Query.Append("   ,SB.B1_XCAS                                                                                ");
        Query.Append("   ,CB.CB0_CODETI AS [COD. BARRAS]                                                            ");
        Query.Append("   FROM SC2020 AS SC                                                                          ");
        Query.Append("   INNER JOIN SB1020 AS SB WITH (NOLOCK) ON SB.B1_COD = SC.C2_PRODUTO                         ");
        Query.Append("   INNER JOIN CB0020 AS CB WITH (NOLOCK) ON CB.CB0_LOTE = SC.C2_XLOTE                         ");
        Query.Append("   WHERE C2_NUM = @C2_NUM                                                                     ");

        comando = conex.CreateCommand();
        comando.CommandText = Query.ToString();

        comando.Parameters.Add("@C2_NUM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_guia.Text.Trim();

        DataTable tableGrid = (DataTable)DGW_EtqPic.DataSource;
        DataTable tableRelatorio = null;

        var filter = from DataRow row in tableGrid.Rows
                     where Convert.ToBoolean(row["SELECIONAR"])
                     select row;
        if (filter.Count() > 0)
        {
            tableRelatorio = filter.CopyToDataTable();

            SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    txt_codbarraspic.Text = reader[11].ToString();
                    txt_cas.Text = reader[10].ToString();
                    etqfracpic.Add("PRODUTO: " + "  " + reader[2].ToString());
                    etqfracpic.Add("FABRICANTE: " + "  " + reader[3].ToString());
                    etqfracpic.Add("ORIGEM: " + "  " + reader[4].ToString());
                    etqfracpic.Add("LOTE" + "  " + reader[5].ToString());
                    etqfracpic.Add("P. BRUTO: " + reader[7].ToString() + "                           " + "P. LIQUIDO: " + "  " + reader[6].ToString());
                    etqfracpic.Add("FABRICAÇÃO: " + "  " + reader[9].ToString() + "               " + "VALIDADE: " + "  " + reader[9].ToString());
                    etqfracpic1.Add("CAS: " + txt_cas.Text.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", ""));
                    etqfracpic.Add("Guia: " + reader[1].ToString());
                    BarcodeLib.Barcode codbarraspic = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
                    codbarraspic.IncludeLabel = true;
                    PB_codbarraspic.BackgroundImage = codbarraspic.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, txt_codbarraspic.Text.Replace(" ", ""), Color.Black, Color.White, 300, 60);
                    Etqpic.Print();
                    etqfracpic.Clear();
                    etqfracpic1.Clear();
                    break;
                }
            }
            conex.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Não tem como te ajudar vendo só uma linha de código.

Comment: Me desculpa coloquei o código completo acima.

Comment: Entendi. Você pode obter uma **Substring()** que retorna uma string com o tamanho desejado.

Veja [Substring](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQl4Xc_tbVAhXFkJAKHX-ED8gQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fpt-br%2Flibrary%2Faka44szs(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGfLzmhdAQPZC-Lq6nmcwpM5dwG-w)

Comment: Exemplo, se for até 80 caracteres o tamanho máximo, pode usar **reader[10].ToString().Substring(0,80);**

Comment: Gilberto boa tarde.Então a sugestão que vc me passou ele para em 80 carácter , mas meu problemas e que tem 120 carácter, e o restante ele não imprimi, para em 80, preciso que quando chegar em 80 ele vá para a linha de baixo e continue os caracteres.

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro coloquei no .NETFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rXtiXi se liberarem aqui, coloco como resposta

Comment: Rovann muito obrigado pela sua ajuda deu certinho aqui...vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [@Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis) deu a resposta á pergunta. Pode usar um método para fazer wrap da string

```
public static string WrapString(string text, int len)
{
    int x =len;
    while (x < text.Length)
    {
        text = text.Insert(x,"\r\n");
        x += len+2;
    }

    return text;
}
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rXtiXi)

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer de forma eficiente e evitar alocações precisa usar o [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;
using System.Text;
                    
WriteLine(WrapString("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789", 10));
WriteLine(WrapString("01234567890123456", 10));
WriteLine(WrapString("012345", 10));

static string WrapString(string text, int len) {
    if (text.Length <= len) return text;
    StringBuilder sb = new(text.Length + text.Length / len * 2);
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < text.Length / 10; i++) {
        sb.Append(text[(i * 10)..(i * 10 + 10)]);
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    if (text.Length / 10 != ToSingle(text.Length) / 10) {
        sb.Append(text[(i * 10)..]);
        sb.Append("\r\n");
} else sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/S4bSrS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMcUpJ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/WrapLine.cs).

Ainda poderia fazer uma otimização quando tem 2 linhas, mas não acho que compensa, em alguns casos pode até ser pior, mesmo sendo melhor, o ganho será irrisório, então fiz só para uma linha.